# Time each CPU core spends in C0 power state

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa, macos, cpu

Any help figuring out how to do this would be great: **How much time each CPU core spent in the C0 power state over the past second.**

This is for a mac app so Objective-C, cocoa and c are needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OS X doesn't have any APIs that expose the c-state of the CPU. However, it seems like you can do this using the MWAIT/MONITOR instructions on intel CPUs. Intel mentions that you can track C-state residency using this technique in section 14.4 of the reference manual:

> Software should use CPUID to discover if a target processor supports the enumeration of MWAIT extensions. If CPUID.05H.ECX[Bit 0] = 1, the target processor supports MWAIT extensions and their enumeration (see Chapter 3, “Instruction Set Reference, A-M,” of Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual, Volume 2A).
>
> If CPUID.05H.ECX[Bit 1] = 1, the target processor supports using interrupts as break-events for MWAIT, even when interrupts are disabled. **Use this feature to measure C-state residency as follows**:
>
> Software can write to bit 0 in the MWAIT Extensions register (ECX) when issuing an MWAIT to enter into a processor-specific C-state or sub C-state.
>
> When a processor comes out of an inactive C-state or sub C-state, software can read a timestamp before an interrupt service routine (ISR) is potentially executed.

You can find more info about the MWAIT instruction in the same manual. Good luck!

[Intel's Reference Manual](http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/manual/253668.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

For getting C0 percentage you should do the following:

Read following MSRs at start and end points of the period you measure:

0x3FC (core c3), 0x3FD (core c6), 0x3FE (core c7), 0x10 (tsc)

Then do the following calculation:

```
Cx_ticks = (c3_after - c3_before) + (c6_after - c6_before) + (c7_after - c7_before)
total_ticks = (tsc_after - tsc_before)
Cx_percentage = Cx_ticks/total_ticks
C0_percentage = 100% - Cx_percentage
```

You can find more information in this [document](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462.pdf) (go to Vol. 3C 35-95)

Comment: Formula is wrong, since C1 is also a thing (see formula in [turbostat.c](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/tools/power/x86/turbostat/turbostat.c?h=v6.1#n1594)). C0 has to be [calculated](https://github.com/fenrus75/powertop/blob/v2.15/src/cpu/intel_cpus.cpp#L737) from the IA32_MPERF (and IA32_APERF?) registers.